# Having issues with an is_prime(x) program in Python?

Tags: python

I apologize for asking such a noobish question, but I'm having an issue writing a very basic program in Python to check whether or not a number is prime.

Here's my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        print ('Please enter a number >= 2.')
    else:
        if x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 5:
            return True
        if x == 4:
            return False
        for num in range (2, int(x/2)):
            if x % num == 0:
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True
```

But this returns True for all odd numbers; not just the prime ones. I'm not understanding why. If someone could point me in the correct direction, it'd be much appreciated! :)

Comment: btw you need not to go to `x/2`, `sqrt(x)` is enough(and also +1 because `range` is exclusive) and you even don't need if's for 2,3,4,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just checks for `num % 2` and returns `True` or `False` depending on the result. So, it returns `True` for all odd numbers. You should just `return True` if the loop does not encounter a `return False`, see the code.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        print ('Please enter a number >= 2.')
    else:
        if x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 5:
            return True
        if x == 4:
            return False
        for num in range (2, int(x/2)):
            if x % num == 0:
                return False
        return True


>>> is_prime(11)
True
>>> is_prime(9)
False
```

**P.S** - You don't need a `break` after a `return`. :)

Comment: You don't need the else after the for loop, you can just return True if the loop finishes.

Comment: @DavidRobinson : Whoops! That missed my mind. Thanks. Fixed. :)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made such a foolish mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Why not do `if x in {2,3,5}`?  It is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, but my focus here was on getting his code to work. I did minimal changes to the code so that OP could relate to it and find out his mistake. :)

Comment: It's a good thing to make the range go to x**0.5 instead of x/2, because if a number is not prime, then it will have two factors that will multiply to get to that number, and one of the factors must be less or equal than the square root(if a number is not prime, again).

Answer (score 0):

This code, which you have inside your loop, prevents the loop from every running more than once; thus you only check for divisibility by 2. This is because the return statement immediately terminates the entire function (thus the break that you have is also redundant):

```
if x % num == 0:
    return False
    break
else:
    return True
```

What you probably want is:

```
for num in range (2, int(x/2)):
    if x % num == 0:
            return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if a number is prime (efficiently) is a really hard task to accomplish, since the primes don't really follow any distinct patterns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

In your code, which is the most intuitive (but inefficient) algorithm, you make the mistake of returning `true` as soon as you see that the number is not divisible by 2. You should run the entire `for` loop before determining that your result is `true`. So what you should do is `return false` if for some `num` in your loop, you find that `x % num == 0`, but otherwise, once you break out of the loop, just return `true`.

EDIT: It appears that other people have answered slightly quicker than I have, so yeah. Just do what they said to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x==2 or (x>2 and x%2):
        return all(x%n for n in xrange(3, int(x**0.5)+1, 2))
    return False
```